# Android BitmapFactory trimming color values from ARGB png

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have an image that contains alpha values. Some of the pixels have transparency of 0, meaning they are completely transparent, others have transparency somewhere between 0 to 255.
Despite pixel being 0 transparency, it still contains valid RGB values which I want to access using bitmap.getPixel(x, y) method.

The problem:
Loaded bitmap loses all RGB values (they are set to 0) where alpha (A) value is 0.

This is how I load bitmap:

```
val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
    inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
}
originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.img, options)
originalImage.setHasAlpha(true)
```

If I open the same image in programs like Gimp, and use color picker on that same pixel, I get all valid RGB values even in those pixels where alpha is 0.

Only those pixels with transparency of 0 are affected, other ones retain their RGB values.

What could be causing it and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android system internally handles bitmap image as premultiplied bitmap by default, all the pixels (stored in the file in non-premultiplied format) are converted to premultiplied pixels while decoding. So, RGB values become 0 where A is 0. If you'd like keep bitmap in non-premultiplied format, just specify [BitmapFactory.Options.inPremultiplied=false](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inPremultiplied).

```
val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
    inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    inPremultiplied = false
}

originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.img, options)
originalImage.setHasAlpha(true)
```